# vs2017 Js editor cannot press F12 jump

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2017 `JS editor` I cannot press <kbd>F12</kbd> jump in my current setup.

In Visual Studio 2013 and Visual Studio 2015 `JS editor` I can press <kbd>F12</kbd> to jump to my function definition.

What should I change in keyboard short-cuts?